# Passing a table from a ScrapySplash Lua Script to Python

Tags: python, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm running ScrapySplash and I'm trying to pass a table created in Lua to the Parse method.  If I try to access the table, then I'm getting a type error saying: 'SplashJsonResponse' object is not subscriptable'.

My Lua Script is as follows:

```
    script = '''
            function main(splash, args)
              assert(splash:go(args.url))
              assert(splash:wait(0.5))
              img = {}
              for i=1,5 do 
                table.insert(img, "Testing")
              end


              return {
                html = splash:html(),
                png = splash:png(),
                har = splash:har(),
                img,
              }
            end
    '''
```

Then my parse method is just:

```
    def parse_item(self, response):
        images = response['img']
        print (images)
```

However, as stated, this will just give me an error on the line images = response['img'] saying 'SplashJsonResponse' object is not subscriptable'.

Anyone have any idea how would I access the values in this Lua table in the parse method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alright, somehow I solved this but I have no idea how.  Basically I changed the return statement in my lua statement as follows:

```
    script = '''
            function main(splash, args)
              assert(splash:go(args.url))
              assert(splash:wait(0.5))
              img = {}
              for i=1,5 do 
                table.insert(img, "Testing")
              end


              return {
                html = splash:html(),
                png = splash:png(),
                har = splash:har(),
                img,
              }
            end
    '''
```

Then in my parse method I had the following:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        images = (response.data['a'])
```

Now I have a dictionary called images, and can access each of the variables through images['i'] though I've no idea why this works but my original method didn't.  If anyone understands why then feel free to comment and let me know.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error `'SplashJsonResponse' object is not subscriptable'` occur because you tried to access key from dictionay response without `data` key.

**Incorrect**: `response['some_key_from_dictionary']`

**Correct**: Incorrect: `response.data['some_key_from_dictionary']`